# 'spring.datasource.testWhileIdle' is an unknown property. Did you mean 'spring.datasource.tomcat.abandon-when-percentage-full'?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on **Spring Boot JDBC MYSQL** example. In this example I had used `1.3.1.RELEASE` spring boot starter version that time I had used the following 2

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

properties which were not showing any warnings. Now when I updated to `1.5.13.RELEASE` its giving me warning. It seems to me that something has changed. I went through **https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html**, but I did not get clear understanding of what has exactly changed. Could anyone please guide ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When in production/RELEASE version, you've to change this

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

to

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

See if it works.